# I need to prove or disprove the claim: $(A-B)-C = A-(B-C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm taking an elementary Abstract Algebra class, and it's been a while...I was wondering if someone would be able to help me out.

Given $3$ sets $A, B$ and $C$, I need to prove or disprove that

$$(A-B)-C = A-(B-C).$$

I'm pretty sure it's false, but I'm not sure how to go about it...

Comment: Try drawing a diagram.

Comment: The answers below are proving the claim false by providing a counter-example for which the claim fails to hold.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}, B=A,C=\{1\}$.

$(A-B)-C=\emptyset-\{1\}=\emptyset$

$A-(B-C)=\{1,2,3\}-\{2,3\}=\{1\}$

Comment: Well I feel dumb, thanks! I was trying to think of how to use contradiction or something...this is much easier :P

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a nonempty set then:

$(X-\varnothing)-X=\varnothing\neq X= X-(\varnothing-X)$